# how to run python/djanjo shell as a script

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

In a tutorial on django we create a simple table run migrations and then go into a shell with the command:

```
python manage.py shell
```

from there, in the shell we run the following:

```
from flights.models import Flight
f = Flight(origin="New York", destination="london", duration=415)
f.save()
```

I'm trying to figure out how to run these commands from a py file so I created test.py:

```
from flights.models import Flight 
f=Flight(origin="New York",destination="London", duration=415)
f.save()
```

but get the error Models aren't loaded. How to resolve? I'm definitely a little confused. I am able to update the database from a web served page with the following in my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render  
from flights.models import Flight

def index(request):
    f=Flight(origin="New York",destination="London", duration=415)
    f.save()
    return render(request, "flights/index.html", {

})
```

What I am asking is how to update the database directly on the backend. Do I just use standard python sql commands?  For instance:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import csv


def sql_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn


def sql_create(conn, create_table_sql):
    """ create a table from the create_table_sql statement
    :param conn: Connection object
    :param create_table_sql: a CREATE TABLE statement
    :return:
    """
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(create_table_sql)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

def sql_insert(conn,sql,data,single):
    cur=conn.cursor()
    if single:
        cur.execute(sql,data)
        rowCount = cur.lastrowid
    else:
        cur.executemany(sql,data)
        rowCount = cur.rowcount

    conn.commit()
    return(rowCount)

def sql_select(conn,sql,data):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql,data)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def sql_update(conn,sql,data):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql,data)
    conn.commit()

def sql_delete(conn,sql,mydata):
    print(mydata)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql,mydata)
    conn.commit()

def main():
    insert = False
    db_file = r"/home/saltydog/Database/crud.db"

    # create a database connection
    conn = sql_connection(db_file)

    # create tables
    sql_create_price_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices (
                                     ticker text NOT NULL,
                                     ymd integer,
                                     price real,
                                     PRIMARY KEY(ticker,ymd)
                                 ); """

    sql_create_price2_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices2 (
                                     ticker text NOT NULL,
                                     ymd integer,
                                     price real,
                                     PRIMARY KEY(ticker,ymd)
                                 ); """


    if conn is not None:
        # create projects table
        sql_create(conn, sql_create_price_table)
        sql_create(conn, sql_create_price2_table)
        conn.commit()

    else:
        print("Error! cannot create the database connection.")

    if(insert):
        sql_insert_record = """insert into prices(ticker,ymd,price)
                               values(?, ?, ?)"""

        cnt = 0
        with open('ibm.txt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                ticker = row[0]
                ymd = row[1]
                price = row[2]
                data = (ticker, ymd, price)
                if cnt != 0:
                    rowid = sql_insert(conn,sql_insert_record,data,True)
                    print(rowid)
                cnt+=1

        sql_insert_records = """insert into prices2(ticker,ymd,price)
                                values(?, ?, ?)"""

        data=[]
        cnt=0
        with open('ibm.txt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                ticker = row[0]
                ymd = row[1]
                price = row[2]
                if cnt != 0:
                    data.append((ticker, ymd, price))
                cnt+=1

        rowid = sql_insert(conn,sql_insert_records,data,False)
        print(rowid)

    select_records = """select ticker,ymd,price from prices
                            where ticker = ?
                            group by price
                            order by price"""

    data=('IBM', )
    rows = sql_select(conn,select_records,data)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)


    select_records = """select ticker,ymd,price from prices
                            where ticker = ?
                            and price > ?"""

    data=('IBM',100.0)
    rows = sql_select(conn,select_records,data)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)



    select_records = """select ticker,ymd,price from prices
                         where ymd = ?"""

    data=(19990527, )
    rows = sql_select(conn,select_records,data)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)


    sql_update_records = """update prices
                            set price = ?
                            where ymd = ?"""

    data = (200.00,19990527)
    sql_update(conn,sql_update_records,data)


    sql_delete_record = """delete from prices where ymd = ?"""
    mydata = (19990528, )
    sql_delete(conn,sql_delete_record,mydata)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You might want to look into django custom commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: that is really helpful, thank you.  so, is there a problem if I update the database directly with sql?